# How can I create a box to input login and password on a web page?

Tags: python, authentication, passwords, box

I'm having trouble getting a library along with the selenium driver for others to enter your login and password by a box that doesn't show the characters (in mask) and put the Login and Password information after you typed directly into the "Login" and "Password" part on the web page.

I did this automatic login to enter the webpage, however I need to make a box to enter the login in place of the login and the password in place of the password for others to access, how can I make and include a box to type and it understands that it should fill in the web location "Login" and "Password" when typed manual without follow the process automatic?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(".........")
a = ActionChains(driver)
username = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username')
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
acessar = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnLogin')
username.send_keys("admin")
password.send_keys("admin")
acessar.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to make simple box using Tkinter (see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xt6SqWuMSA8) tutorial) or search for this: "user login and password tkinter"

Using this simple GUI you set user and password for your selenium script.
You should probably check after summiting with selenium if everthing is ok (maybe checking for a new html tag after you gain access), if not, you shoud display the GUI again to re-enter user data or end the script with login error.

Maybe you can use the box to update status of your selenium.

update: This is not exactly what you ask but can be a simple fix. Two windows asking user and password.

```
import tkinter, tkinter.simpledialog 
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
user = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("User", "Enter user: ", parent=root)
password = tkinter.simpledialog.askstring("Password", "Enter password:", show='*', parent=root)

print (user)
print (password)

root.destroy()
```

Comment: Ok Iam trying to use it to read with the function! Thank you. However It havent work yet as I want.

Comment: hi, another tip if to use Katalon Recorder Extension for google Chrome. It will help you with the selenium code. Check it out: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid

You press record and do what you want in the website. Then press stop and check the generated code for Python language.